# Upper bounds for $\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|$, with $a=(a_1,\dots, a_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, vectors, upper-lower-bounds

Let $n\ge 1$ and $a=(a_1,\dots, a_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a nonnull vector. There is an upper bound for the sum of the magnitude of each component of the vector $a$? I mean, for
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|?$$

I would say that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|\le |a|$$

but I am not sure about that. Here $|a|$ denotes the magnitude of the vector $a$, which is given by
$$|a|=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^2}.$$
Also, I am interested other bounds (maybe finer, if any).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you define the "magnitude of the vector $a$"? (there are many possible norms on $\Bbb R^n$: do you choose the usual Euclidean norm?)

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you for your comment. I am adding that important definition.

Comment: This duplicate proves that $\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|\le \sqrt n|a|,$ and it is the best bound since it is attained when all $a_i$'s are equal.

Comment: @AnneBauval may I ask you why the question you mentioned proves that $\sqrt{n}|a|$ is the best bound? It is not clear to me, I apologize.

Comment: @AnneBauval, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong. Let $a = (3, 4)^\top$:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^2 \lvert a_k \rvert = 7 > \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^2 \lvert a_k\rvert^2} = 5
$$
What you can do for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\lvert x_i \rvert = \max_{k \in \lbrace 1, ..., n \rbrace} \lvert x_k \rvert$ is the following:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert x_k \rvert \leq n \lvert x_i \rvert = n \sqrt{\lvert x_i \rvert^2} \leq n \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^n \lvert x_k \rvert^2 } = n \lvert x \rvert
$$

Comment: For a better answer, see duplicate and comment above.